# How to parse MBR data in file into human form? File command does not work

Tags: linux, mbr

I have MBR data in file and I would like to inspect it. Which Linux command can do this?
WHen I ran

`file mbr.file` the output was only `mbr: DOS/MBR boot sector`

Comment: I think a bit more context is needed.  For me (add the `file` command) MBR = Master Boot Record. Why would you care to see the MBR in a human readable form?

Comment: I am reading about MBR and naturally I would like to inspect it myself. The problem is that on several places is mentioned to use `file` command to display human readable form of MBR but it does not work on openSUSE 13.2. I wonder if there is some command option which I overlook in manual page or something...

Comment: The only thing `file` does is to tell you what type of file it is. Read it's [man page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?file) again. And I highly doubt a MBR would not have a *human readable form*. My best suggestion is read the specs+code for creating/reading a MBR and use a hex-editor

Comment: The [MBR wikipage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record) was surprisingly informative IMO

Comment: Why do you think MBR cannot be translated into normal table by a program? This is one of the links where this trick is mentioned: http://www.miljan.org/main/2007/09/05/easy-way-to-read-mbr/

Comment: @Nifle you are missing the point of this question here. I can read it myself, I just wanted to have the same output as in the mentioned article, nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the latest version of `file` (the MBR stuff was added in 2007... but there were some updates in 2013 that perhaps are affecting you). Either ensure all your software is up to date from your distributions' repository, or grab the latest version of `file` from https://github.com/file/file/ and build it.

The `filesystems` magic pattern is what you are interested in, by the way: https://github.com/file/file/blob/master/magic/Magdir/filesystems. While theoretically you could download that and specify it to `file -m`, the format of that file may not be compatible with older versions of `file`.

If all you're trying to do is view the MBR of a particular device, though (rather than MBR data stored in a file), you can just view the MBR directly with e.g. `parted` or `fdisk` (just be careful to not modify anything).

Answer (score 0):

The `file` command works by using data/templates from a file `/etc/magic`†. It seems your Linux/Unix system has a different `/etc/magic` and/or `file` than the author of that article.

You could try updating or just use a hex dump utility, a calculator and a description of the MBR organisation.

---

† it can be elsewhere, e.g. in `/usr/share/*/magic` - if in doubt try `locate magic` or `sudo find / -name magic`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to view a partition table ( and that's what an MBR is ), then you use a partitioning tool, such as `fdisk` or `parted`.